# Angular2 ngFor produce extra loop

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm trying to use ngFor in Angular 2 rc-1 like this :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myList',
    template: `<h2>Menu</h2>
                {{title}}
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus">
                        {{menu }}
                    <li>
                </ul>`
})
export class MenuComponent {
    title:string = "Our lunch menu";
    menus= ["Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3"];
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is instead of producing 3 bullet/list it end up with 4 bullets with the last bullet without any text.

Could someone have any idea why this is happen or if I did any mistake ?

Thank you

Comment: You must have modified `menus` somewhere else.

Comment: This is not possible. check ur ode again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code

<s>1. You haven't import `CORE_DIRECTIVES` in your component</s>
As said by @Gunter in comment no need to import `CORE_DIRECTIVES` because they are available as part of PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES by default

2. Why your code producing 3 bullet/list it end up with 4 bullets with the last bullet without any text. because in your code there no end tag for `</li>`
   so change your code with this :-

   ```
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#menu of menus; #i=index">
      {{menu}} {{i}} {{menus.length}}
     </li>
   </ul>
   ```

working example <kbd>[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHqS8WbdYh3TUyxeqMCS?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: `CORE_DIRECTIVES` are available as part of `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` by default, no need to import or provide any of these.